# CSS Positioning Issue with :after Pseudo-Element

Tags: css, layout, formatting, positioning, pseudo-element

EDIT: Tinkerbin example located in comments.

The issue I'm running into is with the fixed topbar going behind the slider (only one slide is in there now for testing). This is happening because the light green background used to outline the header is created using an :after pseudo-element on the .page-header class, like so (using SASS):

```
.page-header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 35px 0;
    &:after {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 400px;
        border-bottom: 5px solid $white;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

This places the pseudo-element behind the header, but sill leaves it in front of the slider. I've positioned the slider relatively to place it in front of the pseudo-element, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to adjust so the topbar is always on top. Here the code for the topbar:

```
.nav-cont {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Feel free to take a look at the demo site and let me know if you have any ideas. I've been going through [**Chris Coyier's**](http://css-tricks.com/9516-pseudo-element-roundup/) references along with some others and just can't seem to muster up a solution.

Thanks in advance for anyone who might be able to take a look into this!

Comment: To help us help you, can you provide the simplest possible scenario where you observe this problem, with a demo on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: No problem, [here you go](http://tinkerbin.com/va5liu44).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

`.nav-cont` is a child of the `header`, and because of the weird z-index necessities of the background, it is getting pulled under the slideshow. `z-index` is relative, so with a high `z-index` the navigation could only be the highest thing in the `header`, which was all under the slideshow.

Moving `.nav-cont` out of the `header` and giving it a high z-index solves this problem. Also, strictly speaking, semantically the navigation belongs in a `<nav>` element.

[Fixed example](http://tinkerbin.com/frMnpv3F)

Comment: Thanks, bookcasey! I'll take a look into re-shuffling everything. I was actually just taking a look at TechCrunch's site to see how they handled this and they're doing the same thing. Oh, and I've got the navigation in a `<nav>` element, just stripping everything down to the essentials in the Tinkerbin example. :) I'll definitely be going through and cleaning up the code getting rid of unnecessary markup here in a bit. Thanks for all your help!